# PHP: output a docx file from html

Tags: php, mime-types, docx

Previously I want to output a doc file it is fine.

 But when I change to docx then it told me can't open docx because found a problem with its contents/the file is corrupt. 

If I take out 'echo', then no error occurs but with empty content.
Here is my code:

```
 $fileName = $m_year . "-" . $m_month . "-" . $m_con_id . " - Monthly Report.docx";
 header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
 header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=\"". $fileName ."\"");
 header('Cache-Control: public');
 $content = ets_docMonthlyReportTemplate();
 echo $content;
```

Then I change to vsword, but give me illegal name character. Location: Part:/word/document.xml

```
require_once '/vsword/VsWord.php'; 
VsWord::autoLoad();
$doc = new VsWord(); 
$parser = new HtmlParser($doc);
$content = ets_docMonthlyReportTemplate();
$html= $content;
$parser->parse($html); 
echo '<pre>'.($doc->getDocument()->getBody()->look()).'</pre>'; 
$doc->saveAs($fileName);
```

Can I just output by header MIME Type?or must apply library?

Thanks.

Comment: Changing the mime type header simply changes the mime type header, it doesn't change any of the content that you send to the browser, just suggests how the browser shoud interprets that content.... it doesn't automagically change html markup into a native format docx file.... to actually change that content, you need a library (or to write your own library)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It is clear enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a library to accomplish this.

One of the more popular ones is [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

There is also [VSword](https://github.com/vench/vsword)

There are also paid soluitions [PHPDocx](http://www.phpdocx.com/)

Answer (score 0):

**readfile($fileName);** should solve it

```
`require_once '/vsword/VsWord.php'; 
VsWord::autoLoad();
$doc = new VsWord(); 
$parser = new HtmlParser($doc);
$content = ets_docMonthlyReportTemplate();
$html= $content;
$parser->parse($html); 
echo '<pre>'.($doc->getDocument()->getBody()->look()).'</pre>'; 
$doc->saveAs($fileName);
header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=\"". $fileName ."\"");
readfile($fileName);`
```